# Why is my PIG script failing?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm running a PIG script where I join 2 datasets. I individually verified that the two datasets I'm joining has the expected schema and when I dump the 2 datasets to output, I can see the datasets.

The strange issue I'm having is that my PIG job fails 9 out of 10 times, but succeeds once in a while. The only error message I get is "Internal error creating job configuration". I get this error when I try to perform the JOIN. Unfortunately, I don't have CLI access to the cluster, I can't get a detailed error message. (Jobs are submitted through a REST API). The PIG version is 0.8.

The 2 datasets are fairly small and can be held in memory. So I'm using replicated option. I also tried it without the replicated option. It fails again.

Any idea on whats happenning and how can I solve this problem?

```
SET mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution false;

X = LOAD 'data1' using ....; -- using custom loader
P = LOAD 'data2' using ....; -- using custom loader

-- dataset1
Y = FILTER X BY type MATCHES 'Info' AND name MATCHES 'someregex';
Z = GROUP Y BY name;
A = FOREACH Z GENERATE group, $1.data;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0, FLATTEN(udf1($1));
C = GROUP B ALL;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN(udf2($1)) as (metric1:chararray, count:double, avg: double);

--dataset2
Q = FILTER P BY type MATCHES 'Info' AND name MATCHES 'someother_regex';
R = FOREACH Q GENERATE REPLACE(name,'Percent','') , udf3(records);
S = GROUP R BY $0;
T = FOREACH S GENERATE $0, FLATTEN(udf4(R.$1)) as (q1: double, q2: double, q3: double, q4: double);
-- Each tuple in T is like this: (metric2:chararray, q1: double, q2: double, q3: double, q4: double)

----join the two dataset
I = JOIN D BY $0, T BY $0 USING 'replicated';
STORE I into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Comment: You're saying if you repeatedly try to run your script, sometimes it fails and sometimes it succeeds?

Comment: WinnieNicklaus: Yes. thats right. Particularly, it fails after computing T.

Comment: What are the udf1, ..., udf4? Maybe there is some problem in one of these udfs.

Comment: So you don't have access to the cluster and we are supposed to help?

Comment: Since the pig scripts looks pretty normal I'd try to investigate your "custom loaders"

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of cluster you are using, but on Amazon or Microsoft Azure clusters you can set up an RDP connection to the headnode to get more detailed error messages.